# How to change ColorPrimary when preference is changed?

Tags: android, background-color, android-preferences, preferences

I have an app and I want to change ColorPrimary of app when user select color in settings? How I can do that?

Comment: You should save the setting to SharedPreferences, when display view, load the value from SharedPreferences. And when user select color, you can notify the app that the value was changed by [LocalBroadcastManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager) or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: @maphongba008 ok, but how to change color?

Comment: If you still can't solve your problem, I can give you an example code

Comment: Themes are immutable. To achieve this, you can use `getWindow().setNavigationBarColor()` & `getWindow().setStatusBarColor()` in your `Activity` to change the colors.

Answer (score 0):

When the color is selected in Setting call this method

```
void onBackgroundColor(String color){
        switch(color){
            case "red":
                sSavePreferences(getApplicationContext(), "color", "blue");
                setBackground(color);
                break;
            case "blue":
                sSavePreferences(getApplicationContext(), "color", "blue");
                setBackground(color);
                break;
            case "green":
                sSavePreferences(getApplicationContext(), "color", "blue");
                setBackground(color);
                break;
            default:break;
        }
}
void setBackground(String color){
//code to change background color
}
```

And this is method to save your setting using SharedPreferences

```
public static void sSavePreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

And OnCreate of Activity 
you can load previous color by using this method

```
setBackground(sLoadSavedPreferencesString(getApplicationContext(), "color"));
```

For loading color:

```
public static String sLoadSavedPreferencesString(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    String value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "No Name Found");
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what if i want to change ColorPrimary, instead changing background color?